# I am facing this error while fetching data to admin grid in Magento

Tags: module, adminhtml, collection, grid, magento2.3.5-p1

I am facing this error while fetching data from custom table in Magento 2.3.5

the error is:

```
Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider::searchResultToOutput() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface, instance of Aspl\Contact\Model\ResourceModel\Contact\Grid\Collection given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\M2\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider.php on line 282
```

please if anyone have idea about this problem then just give me solution.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add

use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;

AND need to implement that interface

something like below

```
class Collection extends Collection implements SearchResultInterface
```

Comment: but error not gone still

Comment: please clear cache and check